# phase portrait in dynamics systems

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-dynamics

Write the system

$x'=-y-xy$

$y'=x+x^2 $

in polar coordinates, use

$rr'=xx'+yy'$

$r^2\theta'=xy'-yx'$

Then for above example, have

$r'=0$ and $\theta'=1+x>0$, for $x>-1$.

$r(t)$ is constante and $\theta(t)$ increases without bound, when $t\to \infty$.

We have the point $(0.0)$ and the straight $x=-1$ of equilibrium points.

How can I sketch the phase portrait for this system? I understood that in a neighborhood of the origin has a center, but I am in doubt how the phase portrait looks for different solution curves. Any site where I can plot this system?

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

Making

$$
\cases{
x \dot x = -x y-x^2 y\\
y \dot y = x y + x^2 y
}
$$

after addition we have

$$
\frac 12 \frac{d}{dt}(x^2+y^2) = 0\Rightarrow x^2+y^2= C
$$

are the orbits. Follows a plot showing the stream plot in light blue and the orbit $x^2+y^2=0.5$ in red.

[image]

NOTE

This stream plot has a line $(x = -1)$ with null flux. Thus for $r \lt 1$ the orbits are given by

$$
x^2+y^2 = r^2
$$

while for $r \gt 1$ we have the orbits composed by two circle segments. For example, for $r = 1+\delta,\ \ \delta > 0$ we have

$$
(1+\delta)(\cos\alpha,\sin\alpha),\ \ \ \text{for}\ \ \ \arctan(-1,-\delta(\delta+2))\le \alpha\le \arctan(-1,\delta(\delta+2))
$$

and

$$
(1+\delta)(\cos(-\alpha),\sin(-\alpha)),\ \ \ \text{for}\ \ \ \arctan(-1,\delta(\delta+2))\le \alpha\le \arctan(-1,-\delta(\delta+2))
$$

Comment: How are the orbits along the line x=1?

Comment: @Toy Please. See attached note.

Comment: Thank you very much!! But I'm still in doubt in plotting with respect to the curves of the portrait for x<-1. Can you plot that same drawing with a longer interval? Or would it be the continuity of this but with contrary orientation to x<-1?

Comment: Along the $y=0$ axis, the flow is characterized by a vector which is $(0,x(x+1))$ and obviously for $-1 < x < 0$ this vector has downwards orientation and for $x < -1, x > 0$ it has upwards orientation.

Comment: Yeah, as I had thought!! Thank's.

Comment: @Cesareo, what did you use to plot this?

Comment: I used MATHEMATICA.